# Google Cloud Logs Explorer - query filter do not match pattern

Tags: logging, google-kubernetes-engine

How can I filter all lines in `Logs Explorer` like this.

[image]

When I put the string `{"error":6}` in the input search field it does not work. It did not filter anything. Probably `{}` or `:` are special characters? I tried to put backslash before it but did not work. I also tried filter only `6}` and nothing matched. The filter match only `error`. But I am struggling to add also the number 6 to the filter.

EDIT1:

I tried in search input text field without success:

```
"{error:6}"
\{error:6}\
/{error:6}/
"/{error:6}/"
{"error":6}
{\"error\":6}
/{\"error\"\:6}/
"6}"
6}
```

Another strange thing is, when I see log in `Logs Explorer` it looks like there is `error` in double quotes

```
{"error":6}
```

you can see here:

[image]

but in `Logs` tab there is the `error` without double quotes and with space behind colon:

```
{error: 6}
```

[image]

EDIT2:

When I tried to put `textPayload=~` it did not filter anything. I investigated it more by click the 'log line detail' and found that the `jsonPayload` `{"error":6}` is multilined. Is not possible that that could be the issue?

I tried to put these without success:

```
jsonPayload="{error:6}"
jsonPayload="{\"error\":6}"
```

[image]

Comment: @Rob there are both forms - text and image screenshot. The reason of image is to see the context on the screen in google cloud console.

Comment: @kolisko, I have tried the below query. It's working perfect. 
    severity=ERROR
    textPayload=~"{\"kind\": \"" OR
    textPayload=~"{error: 6}"
    resource.labels.container_name="gke-metrics-agent".   Share the query you are using to find the root cause.

Comment: @kolisko, Also expand the log and share the screenshot of the log field including "error : 6".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution is

```
jsonPayload.error="6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "`jsonPayload`" *LogEntry field* contains a *JSON log field* "error".

In query you can use either `jsonPayload.error="6"` or `jsonPayload.error=6`.

If the *LogEntry field* includes sub fields then you can use `jsonPayload.<field>.<sub-field>`.